# AWS CLI not honoring MultiFactorAuthAge

Tags: aws-cli, multi-factor-authentication

I'm trying to setup my AWS CLI to assume a role using MFA and expiring the creds after 15 minutes (minimum *duration_seconds* allowed, apparently).

My IAM role policy is:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/myuser"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        },
        "NumericLessThan": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "900"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My CLI config is setup as follows:

```
[profile xxx]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/mfa
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:mfa/foobar
source_profile = mfa
```

When I run a command using the `xxx` profile above, MFA is asked the first time and remains valid for all the subsequent requests. However, after 15 minutes, the token is still valid and MFA isn't asked again.

```sh
$ aws s3 ls --profile xxx
```

I tried setting the `duration_seconds` parameter on my CLI as below:

```
[profile xxx]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/mfa
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:mfa/foobar
source_profile = mfa
duration_seconds = 900
```

But now, I'm asked the MFA token for every command issued, even if the time difference is in the order of seconds.

Am I missing something here?

> AWS CLI version: aws-cli/2.0.49 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/19.6.0 exe/x86_64

Appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you try to clear the cache ?
`rm -r ~/.aws/cli/cache`

Comment: Yes, same problem.

Also, the problem seems not to be the credentials returned, since the creds stored in ~/.aws/cli/cache are valid and the expiation time is correct (15 min from now).

Seems like AWS CLI is losing track of the creds and re-asking for authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I discovered the reason for this behavior:

As described in [this Github Issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5880#issuecomment-769243927), AWS CLI treats any session within 15min as expired, refreshing the creds automatically (or asking for a new one-time passcode, in case of MFA).

So, setting the session duration for 15min (900s) is basically the same as getting a one-time credential.

I just tested setting the `session_duration` to `930` (15min + 30s), and the session is indeed valid for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue is with your conditions.

```
"Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
        },
```

This will always require the MFA

instead try something like that:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
    {
            "Sid": "AllowActionsForEC2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances",
               "ec2:DescribeInstances",
               "ec2:StopInstances "],
            "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
           "Sid": "AllowActionsForEC2WhenMFAIsPresent",
           "Effect":"Allow",
           "Action":"ec2:TerminateInstances",
           "Resource":"*",
           "Condition":{
             "NumericLessThan ":{"aws:MultiFactorAuthAge":"300"}
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

The Users with short-term credentials older than 300 seconds must reauthenticate to gain access to this API.

So for your policy it will look like this:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:user/myuser"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "NumericLessThan": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthAge": "900"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is that every conditions needs to be met in order for you to be able to assume the role. `"aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"` will always check if you used the MFA to login.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ben, but it didn't solve the problem.

Setting the trusted relationship as above indeed makes the CLI ask for the MFA, but the credentials returned are valid for one hour (the default), and not 15 min as expected.

If, additionally to your suggestion, I add the option `duration_seconds = 900` to the named profile where I setup the role to assume and MFA device, the credentials returned are valid for 15 min, but the CLI asks for MFA again while the creds are still valid. So, the same problem as before 

Comment: Well that's weird, if I were you I'll create an issue on the Github of the AWS CLI so they could investigate that issue.

Comment: Already there. Waiting for analysis  https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/5880